# Trouble adding static routes in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, configuration, routing, ifconfig

I'm trying to add in static routes into `/etc/networking/interfaces`, but it's not working:

I'm using the following commands per [this](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2018-03-12-using-docker-macvlan-networks/) article in order to connect with my Docker containers using macvlans from the host:

```
ip link add macvlan_host link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.1.8/32 dev macvlan_host
ip link set macvlan_host up
ip route add 192.168.1.51/32 dev macvlan_host
ip route add 192.168.1.61/32 dev macvlan_host
```

The `ip route` command will give me a route like `192.168.1.51 dev macvlan_host scope link`.

I've removed Netplan with `apt purge netplan.io` and installed ifupdown with `apt install ifupdown`.

I'm modifying `/etc/networking/interfaces` to try and reflect the IP commands above. I've tried following [this](https://antonneld.wordpress.com/2018/07/03/giving-the-host-a-macvlan/) guide.

The relevant section of the file is currently:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto macvlan_host
iface macvlan_host inet dhcp
    pre-up ip link add eth0 name macvlan_host type macvlan mode bridge
    post-up route add -net 192.168.1.51/32 dev macvlan_host
    post-up route add -net 192.168.1.61/32 dev macvlan_host
```

This question is somewhat similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199412/translating-this-ip-command-to-route-command-in-post-up-hook), but differs in that my routes are not using the `via` and a static IP.

The add route commands in the file aren't adding in the routes as the commands earlier do and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm using Server 20.04. I've replaced Netplan as I don't believe it supports macvlans.